# Closure issue with creating listeners for emitted events

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures, eventemitter

I've implemented a object that encapsulates a driver which interacts with external devices. When the driver receives data it emits an event.

When I start, I load a list of all defined drivers. Then I iterate through the definitions to do the following:

- create a driver instance,
- listen for the events on the driver, and
- tell the driver to connect.

As a part of the listener for the emitted event I define a function that is passed some details on what the device represents.

However my code appears to have a problem. When a driver emits an event, the function that is fired only shows one set of details. These details are the last ones defined in the for loop where I create the drivers and listen for the events.

I've created a test example that recreates my problem by using a couple of simple objects and a timer. This will need to be run in node.js to see the problem.

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util         = require('util');

// define vehicle object
function Vehicle(options) {
    options = options || {};
    this.id = ((options.id != null) ? options.id : -1);
    this.name = ((options.name != null) ? options.name : 'unknown');
}

util.inherits(Driver, EventEmitter);

// define driver object
function Driver(options) {
    options = options || {};
    this.id = ((options.id != null) ? options.id : -1);
    this.name = ((options.name != null) ? options.name : 'unknown');
}

Driver.prototype.startTimer = function(delay) {
    self = this;

    console.log('starting timer for ' + self.name + ' with a delay of ' + delay);

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('firing timer for ' + self.name);
        self.emit('timer', 'some data');
    }, delay);
}

// function to create listener
function makeOnTimerFunction(driver, vehicle) {
    console.log("creating function for d name : " + driver.name + ' d id: ' + driver.id + ' v id: ' + vehicle.id + ' v name: ' + vehicle.name);
    return function(d) {
        console.log(" d name: " + driver.name + ' d id: ' + driver.id + ' v id: ' + vehicle.id + ' v name: ' + vehicle.name + ' d: ' + d);
    }
}

var vehicles = new Array();
vehicles.push(new Vehicle({id: 1001, name: 'Max'}));
vehicles.push(new Vehicle({id: 1002, name: 'Cheif'}));
vehicles.push(new Vehicle({id: 1003, name: 'Seigfreid'}));
var driver = null;

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    driver = new Driver({
        id: vehicles[i].id,
        name: vehicles[i].name,
    });

    driver.on('timer', makeOnTimerFunction(driver, vehicles[i]));
    driver.startTimer(1000 * i);
}
```

```

The output I get is as follows:

```
creating function for d name : Max d id: 1001 v id: 1001 v name: Max
starting timer for Max with a delay of 0
creating function for d name : Cheif d id: 1002 v id: 1002 v name: Cheif
starting timer for Cheif with a delay of 1000
creating function for d name : Seigfreid d id: 1003 v id: 1003 v name: Seigfreid
starting timer for Seigfreid with a delay of 2000
firing timer for Seigfreid
 d name: Seigfreid d id: 1003 v id: 1003 v name: Seigfreid d: some data
firing timer for Seigfreid
 d name: Seigfreid d id: 1003 v id: 1003 v name: Seigfreid d: some data
firing timer for Seigfreid
 d name: Seigfreid d id: 1003 v id: 1003 v name: Seigfreid d: some data
```

What I expect to see is as follows:

```
creating function for d name : Max d id: 1001 v id: 1001 v name: Max
starting timer for Max with a delay of 0
creating function for d name : Cheif d id: 1002 v id: 1002 v name: Cheif
starting timer for Cheif with a delay of 1000
creating function for d name : Seigfreid d id: 1003 v id: 1003 v name: Seigfreid
starting timer for Seigfreid with a delay of 2000
firing timer for Max
 d name: Max d id: 1001 v id: 1001 v name: Max d: some data
firing timer for Chief
 d name: Chief d id: 1002 v id: 1002 v name: Chief d: some data
firing timer for Seigfried
 d name: Seigfreid d id: 1003 v id: 1003 v name: Seigfreid d: some data
```

The issue is that the timer is always referencing the last object, named Seigfreid.

---- edit ----

Just to make the problem clear the problem appears to be with the `makeOnTimerFunction` function. The function it returns is the function to fire when an event occurs. When `makeOnTimerFunction` is called, the variables all make sense. However when the event fires and the function returned by `makeOnTimerFunction` is called then the variables are always the same. They do not reflect the values when `makeOnTimerFunction` was first called.

Comment: Have you tried closing over the `i` in the final `for` loop?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean Kieran sorry, I've done a bit of reading about closures and thought I was handling all the variables okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
Driver.prototype.startTimer = function(delay) {
  self = this; <----
```

You're effectively creating a global variable `self`, which gets overwritten every time you run the `startTimer` method. In the end, it will be overwritten so it points to the last driver instance, hence your unexpected results.

Solution: use `var` to create a new variable scoped to the method:

```
Driver.prototype.startTimer = function(delay) {
  var self = this;
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, the cause is kinda embarrassing, but thank you for finding it. :-)